# Removing Parts of a File Name based on a Delimiter

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I have various file names that are categorized in two different ways. They either just have a code like: "866655" or contain a suffix and prefix "eu_866655_001". My hope is to write to a text file the names of files in the same format. I cannot figure out a successful method for removing the suffix and prefix.

Currently this what I have in my loop in Powershell:

```
$docs = Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '.doc*'}

if ($docs.basename -contians 'eu_*')
{
 Write-Output ([io.fileinfo]"$doc").basename.split("_")
}
```

I'm hoping to turn "eu_866655_001" into "866655" by using "_" as the delimiter.

I'm aware that the answer is staring me down but I still can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Shouldn't it match `'*.doc'` instead of `'.doc*'`?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs it's fail safe in case the file is older, therefore meaning it could be either a .doc or .docx

Comment: [1] the `-match` operator uses _regex_ ... that means the dot & the asterisk are both going to do something other than what you expect. [*grin*] try using `-like '*.doc*` instead. ///// [2] you need to iterate thru the collection instead of acting on the whole thing in your IF block. ///// [3] there is no need to use `[io.fileinfo]` since the objects are already `fileinfo` objects. ///// [4] you want the 2nd item from the split, not all of them - so use `.Split('_')[1]` to get that item.

Comment: To avoid problems with matching/regex, an alternative is to do something like this:  `Get-ChildItem -Path $source -file | Where-Object Extension -in '.doc','.docx'`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following. Feel free to tweak the `-Filter` on the `Get-ChildItem` command.

```
$source = 'c:\path\*'
$docs = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -File -Filter "*_*_*" -Include '*.doc','*.docx'
$docs | Rename-Item -NewName { "{0}{1}" -f $_.Basename.Split('_')[1],$_.Extension }
```

The important things to remember is that in order to use the `-Include` switch, you need an `*` at the end of the `-Path` value.

**Explanation:**

- `-Filter` allows us to filter on names that contain two underscores separating three substrings.
- `-Include` allows us to only list files ending in extensions `.docx` and `.doc`.
- `Rename-Item -NewName` supports delayed script binding. This allows us use a scriptblock to perform any necessary operations for each piped object (each file).
- Since the target files will always have two underscores, the `.Split('_')` method will result in an three index array delimited by the `_`. You have specified that you always want the second delimited substring and that is represented by index 1 (`[1]`).
- The format operator (`-f`) puts the substring and extension together, completing the file name.

Comment: There was no request to rename files but: *`My hope is to write to a text file the names of files in the same format.`* Otherwise, nice one (+1).